# Unable to get button click event notification in xamarin.Android.Tooltip by jzeferino

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I tap the button I can able get the tooltip but I can't able to get an event `triggered.Btn_Clicked` is not triggered. I'm using the sample and plugin from here https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/01/showing-tooltips-in-xamarin-forms/

```
<Button
    x:Name="btn"
    effects:TooltipEffect.BackgroundColor="Silver"
    effects:TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="True"
    effects:TooltipEffect.Position="Bottom"
    effects:Toeffects:TooltipEffect.TextColor="Teal"
    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
    Clicked="Btn_Clicked"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Text="Showooooooooooo"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    WidthRequest="150">
</Button>
```

Comment: somebody, please provide me solution

Comment: I just add your code in the sample and the `Btn_Clicked` did triggered, what's your problem?

Comment: its working in button not in image

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton instead of image.It Works